# Improve prediction with LSTMs when data have no particular trend (complex)

Tags: deep-learning

I have a deep learning problem, I am working with the CMAPSS dataset, which contains data simulating the degradation of several aircraft engines. The aim is to predict from data collected on a machine in full operation, the remaining useful time at this machine. My problem is the following when the features (sensor data) have a specific trend (either up or down), my model (LSTMs) predicts good results but when the data have no trend, my deep learning model gets a very bad score. I must specify that I work with sequential data. my dataset contains several aircraft engines with data recorded by the sensors. my question is how to process the data that has no particular trend in deep learning.

You will find below some pictures of my dataset where, RUL: is the life of a machine, unit: the machine identity and s1 to s3 is the sensor data.
[image]